# The preceding token is not quantifiable

Tags: regex, go

I have a username regular expression like this:

```
/^(?=.{5,32}$)(?![1-9_])(?!.*_{2})\w+(?<!_)$/gm
```

About regexp:

1. The first character is a letter.
2. You cannot use 2 underscores in a row.
3. There can be no underscore at the end.
4. The characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (\w) are allowed.
5. 5 to 32 characters

I can't use it in Go because of lookahead and lookbehind.

> The preceding token is not quantifiable

**Question:**

How to simulate these lookahead and lookbehind in Go Regexp to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it seems you may refactor the pattern to use in JavaScript: `/^(?=.{5,32}$)[^\W0-9_][^\W_]*(?:_[^\W_]+)*$/`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUZR2a/1).

Now, it is easy to convert it to Go, with two separate checks: 1) the stirng length can be checked without a regex, 2) the overall pattern check can be done with the consuming JS regex part:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    s := "abc_123def"
    whole_cond := regexp.MustCompile(`^[^\W0-9_][^\W_]*(?:_[^\W_]+)*$`)
    pass_len := utf8.RuneCountInString(s)
    fmt.Println(whole_cond.MatchString(s) && pass_len >= 5 && pass_len <= 32)
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/hN8sDAk3DOR).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\W0-9_]` - any word char but an ASCII digit and `_`
- `[^\W_]*` - 0+ word chars but `_`
- `(?:_[^\W_]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `_` - `_` char
  - `[^\W_]+` - 1+ word chars except `_`
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thanks for the details!